# Binding issue in custom user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created a usercontrol but I can not make the binding work, I tried in many ways but I did not get it to work, the value is not displayed.

**ShowPrice.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(ShowPrice),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                (
                    string.Empty,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal |
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                    OnValuePropertyChanged
                ));

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var showPrice = obj as ShowPrice;
        showPrice?.SetValue(ValueProperty, (string)e.NewValue);
    }
```

**ShowPrice.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.CustomControls.UserControls.ShowPrice"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="40"
                   Margin="5" />

</UserControl>
```

**My view.xaml**

```
<userControls:ShowPrice Value="{Binding MyViewModelProperty, StringFormat=C2, ConverterCulture='es-AR'}">
</userControls:ShowPrice>
```

If I write a value if it works

```
<userControls:ShowPrice Value="Test"/>
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is that the view model is not bound to your view, because it is not finding MyViewModelproperty. As you say, if you set "Value" explicitly it works, so the problem is not in ShowPrice.xaml.

Comment: Also you don't need the line "showPrice?.SetValue(ValueProperty, (string)e.NewValue);" It's redundant of the Value property setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind `DataContext` to `Self`. Use a RelativeSource binding instead (but this isn't the problem):

```
Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Also, get rid of your `OnValuePropertyChanged` handler. It's called when `Value` is set, so it's hardly necessary to set `Value` again (but that's not the problem either).

Finally, this may be your problem:

```
Foreground="White"
```

Is this thing being used on a white background? I kept all of your code exactly as you had it, and made one change:

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding Value}"
    Background="YellowGreen"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="White"
    FontSize="40"
    Margin="5" 
    />
```

This:

```
    Background="YellowGreen"
```

And I saw white text on a yellow-green background.

Comment: Thanks for the example, my code is bigger, there is a border with a colored background, I just put that piece of code, just the part of the error. The problem was solved by removing the Self DataContext